# How to restrict documents number requested in Firestore security rules?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

We are developing a SaaS solution for gyms and fitness centers.

There are 3 packages. The first one is free for the first 50 members they add in the system. Then an upgrade is required to add more members.

There is a security rule in place to prevent more members to be added after reaching that limit. The problem is that if the subscription is upgraded and then downgraded.

Let's say they upgraded, add 100 members in total and then downgraded to the free plan which only includes 50 members.

In this case we want to allow them to only get the last 50 members they added to members collection. In other words we want to restrict access to request of over 50 members documents.

```
match /_users/{memberId} {
    allow read: if isMemberAuthenticated(memberId) || isGymAuthenticated();
    allow update: if isGymAuthenticated() || isMemberAuthenticated(memberId);
    allow create: if isGymPaid() && isGymAuthenticated();
}
```

**Solutions we considered are:**

- Having an ID number in the members document and restrict access to any request with ID < subscription allowed. The problem is that user has access to the member documents and thus can alter their IDs.
- Have a Firebase Cloud unction to request the members documents and remove user write access. This looks like an anti-pattern for Firestore. As we have to implement cloud functions for any change a user does on the member documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the user to update some field in a document, you can write a security rule to check that the user is not changing the value of that field.  The problem is that you currently can't stop the client from trying to request a different query that doesn't use the ID field as a filter.  You also can't use security rules to filter (remove) documents from a query that would normally be part of the results.

You might want to look into use of [request.query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#query) to help limit the overall number of documents from a query, but this requires the client to limit their own results.

Using Cloud Functions to gate access to the database is not an anti-pattern.  Sometimes it's necessary to be able to enforce things that can't be expressed by security rules.  Sometimes people use Cloud Functions triggers to remove or clean up invalid data after it's been added as well.